# Summing elements in a multi-dimensional array within a certain area

Tags: python, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am creating a game where a robot traverses a map that is a 2D array. Each spot in the 2D array has a "treasure" that is a number of coins. I want to be able to add all the elements up to 4 places up, down, right, and left from the robots current position (making a "plus" sign). So, if we have an array:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4]
      [5, 6, 7 ,8]
      [9, 10, 11, 12]
      [13, 14, 15, 16]
```

If the robot was standing on `a[0][0]` (at the 1 position), the sum would return `1+2+3+4+5+9+13`. If he was standing on `a[1][2]` (the 7 spot), it would return `(7+3)+(8)+(5+6)+(11+15)`. But I want it to return only up to 4 places. In the end, I want to find the best spot for the robot to be.

This is the code I have:

```
def the_place_to_be(a):
    maximum = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        # Looping through columns
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            # Looping through rows
            sum_at_ij = a[i][j]
            for x in range(i - max_steps_in_direction(a, i, "up"), i):
                sum_at_ij += a[x][j]

            for x in range(j - max_steps_in_direction(a[i], j, "left"), j):
                sum_at_ij += a[i][x]

            for x in range(i, i + max_steps_in_direction(a, i, "down")):
                sum_at_ij += a[x+1][j]

            for x in range(j, j + max_steps_in_direction(a[i], j, "right")):
                sum_at_ij += a[i][x+1]

            if sum_at_ij >= maximum:
                maximum = sum_at_ij
                coordinates = "(" + str(i) + ", " + str(j) + ")"
    return maximum, coordinates


def max_steps_in_direction(a, idx, direction):
    if direction == "up" or direction == "left":
        return min(idx, 4)
    elif direction == "down" or direction == "right":
        return min(len(a) - idx - 1, 4)
```

This probably has the crappiest time complexity. I am looking through the entire array, then looping through all the elements up to four places away from the coordinate the robot is standing in, in the top, bottom, right, and left directions.

In every step, I am calculating values more than I have to. Is there a way to mitigate this? I was thinking maybe my variable `sum_at_ij` can be saved. I am basically moving through each list inside the multi-list. At each point in the list, I am really only calculating *some* values that are different from the previous coordinate. So, again, say I was at coordinate `a[2][2]`, or coordinate 11, when I move to `a[2][3]`, or coord 12, the differences are in:

> sum_at_22: 11 + 7 + 3 + 15 + 12 + 10 + 9
>
> sum_at_23: 12 + 8 + 4 + 16 + 11 + 10 + 9

I am calculating a  total of 3 new values (the top and bottom ones are different). If this was an 8x8 matrix, the new values would be the top values, bottom values, and one new value on the right and one less value on the left. And if I saved every value (probably in some hashmap), then maybe I can find some formula.. I don't know, to be honest. Maybe this is a math.stackexchange question.

Any ideas how I could save computation time at (yes, its okay) the expense of memory?

Comment: How about making the field a numpy array and using slicing and its sum function?

Comment: @jotasi seems like an excellent answer that needs some clarification :)

Comment: If i get correctly then a[1][2] (the 7 spot), it would 7+3+6+5+8+11+15  but you are saying a[1][2] (the 7 spot), it would return (7+1)+(8)+(5+6)+(11+15)  ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Good catch! You are totally right

Comment: @JohnLexus array size would be same or it can be small and large (arbitrary size ) ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul  I'm not sure what you mean. This is a matrix that is NxN ,if  that answers your question

Comment: @JohnLexus ok and as you said it would return (7+3)+(8)+(5+6)+(11+15). But I want it to return only up to 4 places.   so it means you don't want (7+3)+(8)+(5+6)+(11+15)  ? or what do you mean by 4 places ? (7+3) is 1 place or you mean (7+3+something +something)  is 4 places ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Since "7" is the starting point (the coordinate you are standing on), 4 places would be 7 + (x + y+ z + w). So if you had an array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, 4 places to the left from a[5] (or at coordinate 6) would be 5 + 4 + 3 + 2

Comment: Can the values in the matrix change after initialization?

Comment: @samgak no they cannot

Comment: @JohnLexus I have left the last step as an exercise . However feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your summing procedure is effectively a convolution with a + shaped filter. You can get this much faster if you replace your explicit loops with one call to the [`convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) function of scipy which will do all the necessary looping for you but not in python but in C:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# Your original array:
a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [5, 6, 7 ,8],
                [9, 10, 11, 12],
                [13, 14, 15, 16]])

# Building a filter that is essentially a + with arms of length 4
mask = np.zeros((2*4+1, 2*4+1))
mask[4, :] = 1
mask[:, 4] = 1

# Apply that filter to your array
sums = convolve2d(a, mask, mode="same")

# Find the maximum and its position in the sums array:
np.max(sums), np.unravel_index(np.argmax(sums), sums.shape)
```

In the end, sums is the array giving the value of your summing procedure for each position in the original array. You are only left to find the maximum and its position.

While the complexity might not be better than that of your solution, it will still be much faster, as python loops are extremely slow, whereas a lot of machinery in numpy and scipy is written in C/Fortran, speeding up the computations.

Timing your solution vs. this one on a 100x100 array gives a speed-up-factor of approx. 40 on my machine (78.7ms vs 2.06ms).

Comment: Freaking love this solution!

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is much faster and cleaner, although I think Sumeet's answer is  the "better" one in terms of time complexityt

Comment: @JohnLexus Btw for a mask size much smaller than the array size, all three solutions (yours, Sumeet's and mine) have complexity N*N as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh, really? I thought mine would be more than n^2. But now that I think about it, you're right, this is n^2

Comment: It's not that simple I guess, because at least in your example, the number of steps is of the order of the array size. In that case, the complexity is worse. But as soon as the array becomes much larger than the number of steps, you are left with two loops and something taking constant (number-of-step-dependend) time. Or do I overlook something here?

Comment: No, you are absolutely correct. My initial reservations to classifying this as O(n^2) were exactly what you said: initially, when the 2D array is small, the time complexity is significantly worse than O(n^2). But if we have an array size of 100000, the time complexity won't really change because of those extra steps I added inside the second for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having **2 auxiliary matrices** of exactly same dimension as the input matrix.

Now let the first one be **row** and the second one be **column**. The row matrix is populated as:

```
row[i][j] = sum of(a[i][0] + a[i][1] +....a[i][j-1])
```

which you can do easily in time **O(N*N)** by traversing your input array in row major order . The column matrix is populated as:

```
column[i][j] = sum of(a[0][j] + a[1][j] +....a[i-1][j])
```

which you can also do easily in time **O(N*N)** by traversing your input array in column major order.

Now get your position by traversing your input array once and total complexities are:

Time complexity = **O(N*N)**

Space complexity = **O(N*N)**

Comment: This is the better answer in terms of time-complexity and was basically exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm. Wish I could also accept this answer!

Comment: @JohnLexus You can accept any answer if it fulfills your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [numpy slicing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_indexing_and_slicing.htm) -

```
import numpy as np


def get_sum(matrix, row, col):
    # Get the sum of 4 numbers to the left
    sum_left_4_numbers = matrix[row, max(col - 4, 0):col].sum()
    # Get the sum of 4 numbers to the right
    sum_right_4_numbers = matrix[row, col:col + 4].sum()
    # Get the sum of 4 numbers above
    sum_top_4_numbers = matrix[max(row - 4, 0):row, col].sum()
    # Get the sum of 4 numbers below
    sum_bottom_4_numbers = matrix[row + 1: row + 4, col].sum()
    return sum_left_4_numbers + sum_right_4_numbers + sum_top_4_numbers + sum_bottom_4_numbers

matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])
print get_sum(matrix, 1, 2)
# Output - 55
```

Comment: He want's to find the maximum sum though and thus your solution needs looping over all elements to find the maximum anyway.

Comment: Yes. It is just faster than using python lists, because of numpy. Not a significant improvement, though.